# Writing a comment or an answer to add important info

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about a problem I came across and got an answer, which mostly consists of screenshots and that describes a way of accomplishing what I asked for but in a general way.

Following the steps suggested didn't fix my problem because the answer is missing a single important info, which I found myself after the answer had already been posted.

Should I now add this info as a comment to the answer, so the author can add it, edit the answer myself or write my own answer with the important info, referencing the other answer?

Answer (score 3):

*It depends.*

I would only edit the answer, if the additional information is a very small addition (e.g. one sentence), and if it does not change the meaning of the original answer.

If your addition is as long as the original answer, or if the meaning is different, I'd write another answer.

Commenting is always a good option, as you leave the decision to the original answerer. However, comments are meant to have a short life, they might be deleted somewhen, so if the information is supposed to stay, I'd write it into an answer.

Comment: Honestly, I'd rather have the other guy's answer contain more text instead of mostly screenshots, that's why I am/was reluctant to edit it. Additional to the info I'd also add more text because images can always just vanish but that would most likely not get accepted as an edit. The additional info is indeed more or less a single sentence and while I could probably find some more stuff to write to explain it, it would still be a short paragraph max. Is a comment/edit the best solution then here? If I decided to write an answer, how would I go about accepting? Accept mine, upvote the other guy?

Comment: You mean [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728370/xcode-11-2-is-missing-simulators) ? The question is closed ... so you can't add an answer.

Comment: Yes, that one would be an example. I'm aware it's closed, I already asked the guy about it but I've come across the same question (comment, answer or edit) multiple times already and usually ended up writing a comment, hoping that someone would actually see it.